# Trouble using ‘this.files’ in GruntJS Tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Background:
So I’m new to writing grunt tasks, so hopefully this isn’t a stupid question.
Purpose of my grunt task: Given a file (html / jsp / php / etc) search all the link / script tags, compare the href / src to a key, and replace with the contents of the file.  Proposed task configuration:

```
myTask:{
      index:{
          files:{src:"test/testcode/index.html", dest:"test/testcode/index.html"},

          css:[
              {
                  file: "/css/some/css/file.css",
                  fileToReplace:"/target/css/file.css"
              },
              {
                  file: "/css/some/css/file2.css",
                  fileToReplace:"/target/css/file2.css"
              }
          ],
          js:[
              {
                  file: "/css/some/css/file.css",
                  fileToReplace:”/target/css/file.css"
              },
              {
                  file: "/css/some/css/file2.css",
                  fileToReplace:"/target/css/file2.css"
              }
          ]
      }
  }
```

Problem:
Now, per my understanding, when dealing with files, you should reference the ‘this.files’ object because it handles a bunch of nice things for you, correct?  Using intelliJ and the debugger, I see the following when i watch the ‘this.files’ object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzAx0.png  What I would expect to see is src and dest to be the same, not dest ===‘src’ and src === undefined.

So, What is it that I am missing? Is there some documentation on ‘this.files’ I can read about?   I’ve tried setting the files attribute in the target to a number of other formats per grunts spec, none seem to work (for this script, ideally the src / dest would be the same, so the user would just have to enter it once, but i’m not even getting in to that right now.)

Thanks for the help

EDIT:
The underlying issue here is that I was using IntelliJ for debugging.  For some reason, when i did a watch on this.files the src var (along with this.fileSrc var ) never was updated. even when I would see other items getting updated when appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Configuring Tasks portion of the docs: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

`this.files` works with supported configuration formats listed on the configuring tasks page:

```
task: {
  target: {
    src: 'source',
    dest: 'destination',
  },
},
```

OR

```
task: {
  target: {
    files: [
      { src: 'source', dest: 'destination' },
      { src: 'source2', dest: 'destination2' },
    ],
  },
},
```

OR

```
task: {
  'destination': 'source',
},
```

OR

```
task: {
  target: {
    files: {
      'destination': 'source',
      'destination2': 'source2',
    },
  },
},
```

Read more about `this.files`: http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.files

Comment: Yup, I've tried all of those, and none of them seem to work.  The Destination always is set however the src is always undefined...  If it would help I can provide the code.

Comment: Yep, please do. Double check your syntax to match the above. Make sure your are not nesting targets or tasks.

Comment: Kyle, I've run these and come up with the same issue.  File can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ESswN4sX  Seems like I'm doing something wrong, I just have no idea what, doesn't seem like it should be this hard :P  Thanks again for the help! -Andrew

Comment: `'source'` and `'destination'` were just examples and they should be actual files on your system. If you want Grunt to warn you when a file you gave it doesn't exist, add `nonull: true` and it will let you know when it couldn't find a file you gave it.

Comment: I understand that, however my point is, it should have given ~something~  the src array should not be undefined... right?  Even when I put real files in there, it still comes back as undefined.

Comment: Would you mind updating your pastebin with the latest you're trying? Also which version of grunt and node.js are you using? It should work, all of Grunt is built upon this. If this didn't work, everybody's code would be broken :) So Im guessing you have a misconfiguration somewhere I can't see.

Comment: Sooooooooooo here is the deal.  I was using the IntelliJ Debugger, and for some reason this seems to not work.  reference: http://imgur.com/mBJ5NiE  So, when I use console.log( this.files[0].src ) that spits out the proper items.  So, long story short, I was doing it properly, you were pointing me in the right direction, and I'm chalking this up to IntelliJ debugger not properly showing the variable.  Thanks for the help (and patience) @Kyle I appreciate it.